# Calculate number of days between two ZonedDateTime objects in a specific time zone?

Tags: java

I have the following snippet of code where I have two date objects `dates[0]` and `dates[1]`. Both are converted to GMT+10 time zone. I'm trying to find the days (logical calendar days) between these two dates **in the GMT+10 time zone**, not in UTC.

I've tried `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()`, such as below, but I believe it's converting the dates to UTC first (I expected the below to print 1 and 0, but it prints 0 and 0.)

```
Date[] dates = new Date[2];
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
dates[1] = formatter.parse("2018-12-04T12:00:00");
dates[2] = formatter.parse("2018-12-04T16:00:00");
long toDate = 1543942800000L; \\2018-12-04T17:00:00
String timeZone = "GMT+10";
ZonedDateTime toDateZoned = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(toDate),
    ZoneId.of(timeZone)
);
for (Date ele: dates) {
    ZonedDateTime eleZoned = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
        ele.toInstant(),
        ZoneId.of(timeZone)
    );
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(eleZoned,toDateZoned));
}
```

if I replace the last print statement with

```
System.out.println(eleZoned);
System.out.println(toDateZoned);
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(eleZoned, toDateZoned));
```

I get the following output

```
2018-12-04T22:00+10:00[GMT+10:00]
2018-12-05T03:00+10:00[GMT+10:00]
0
2018-12-05T02:00+10:00[GMT+10:00]
2018-12-05T03:00+10:00[GMT+10:00]
0
```

Comment: you need to set the TimeZone of the SimpleDateFormat to ensure it is parsing the dates in the correct time zone.

Comment: @jtahlborn this shouldn't matter since it's being converted to a ZonedDateTime object in the time zone of `timeZone` within the for loop right?

Comment: Date and epoch millis are effectively "zoned" date times (in the UTC zone).  in order to get a correct epoch value, you _have_ to parse your local date time using the correct timezone.

Comment: note, you can easily verify that your dates are being correctly parsed by outputting them in the loop after you convert them to ZonedDateTime instances.

Comment: Yes, I believe they are being parsed correctly; if I add `System.out.println(eleZoned);` I get the expected output

Comment: that would work if your system default timezone is already gmt+10

Comment: I've updated the question to include some output. The ChronoUnit.Days.between is returning 0 even when the dates lie on different days in GMT+10.

Comment: neither one of those days have a _complete unit_ between them, so both should be 0.

Comment: (also note that the first dates are _not_ being parsed in the GMT+10 timezone as you can see that they print out with different values than the original strings)

Comment: are you trying to determine the number of calendar days between two dates?

Comment: From the output they are being parsed correctly I think? At least from the output (add 10 hours to the dates in dates array). And yes, calendar days.

Comment: if your original strings are _already_ in GMT+10, then no, they aren't being parsed correctly.

Comment: Ah I see. The strings have no indication of time zone so they should be parsed as UTC. The output makes me believe so at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the calendar days between the dates, you can convert them to LocalDate before calling `between()`.

```
Date[] dates = new Date[2];
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+10");
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
dates[0] = formatter.parse("2018-12-05T12:00:00");
dates[1] = formatter.parse("2018-12-04T16:00:00");
long toDate = 1543942800000L; //2018-12-04T17:00:00
String timeZone = "GMT+10";
ZonedDateTime toDateZoned = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(toDate),
    ZoneId.of(timeZone));
for (Date ele: dates) {
  ZonedDateTime eleZoned = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
      ele.toInstant(),
      ZoneId.of(timeZone));
  System.out.println("Dates " + eleZoned + " " + toDateZoned);
  System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(eleZoned,toDateZoned));
  System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(eleZoned.toLocalDate(),toDateZoned.toLocalDate()));
```